# DataFormWebPart cannot sort item with Last modified properly

Tags: date-time, sorting, data-form-web-part

In my DataFormWebPart, I have set sort by Modifed column. The column is display with follow format:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Modified), 2057, 5)"/>
```

However, when sorting with descending order. The time at 12:xx is at higher proirity:

> 24/04/2015 12:44
>
> 24/04/2015 12:25
>
> 24/04/2015 17:18
>
> 24/04/2015 16:55
>
> 24/04/2015 15:52

Why is that?